# Is this service going to die when activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a custom class which checks conditions and then runs MyService, otherwise it just does nothing if conditions are false. An instance of my custom class is created within MainActivity of an app.

Inside MyService: onStartCommand: returns sticky, onCreate: new thread is going to be created, in that thread, inside of a runnable the other stuff is going to be done, like creating new threads, async tasks and etc. The service has nothing to do UI except Notifications.

Is there any other ways for MyService to die except user kills it or system runs out of memory?

Comment: stopSelf,  is it what you mean?

Comment: why and how would this method invoked?

Comment: " Is there any other ways for MyService to die ", so stopSelf kills your Service

Comment: But I am never calling stopSelf.

Comment: How about START_NOT_STICKY?

Comment: That wouldnt make service start up again when its killed.

Comment: Simply start it when the app starts, then it starts and dies together with the app, as far as I understand.

Comment: You can use `stopService` as well when you destroy your activity, or when you see it fit.

Answer (score 0):

Service will die if user removes application from recent apps. Also, if application gets crash, service will die. 
 If you want to run service even if low memory condition, start running service in foreground. But running service in foreground will cause a notification displayed continuously. 
 Service running in foreground is not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory. You can show your custom notification in case of foreground service as below :

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Add above code in service class.
Even after passing notification as NULL, system will show his own notification using application default title and icon.

Check this link for more details http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground